# How to prove that any function $f(x)$ is linear in the infinitesimal limit

Tags: linear-algebra

I have tried to prove this in the following way. I have expanded the function $f(x)$ near $a$  in a Taylor series.
$$f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+f''(a)(x-a)^2/2!+\cdots\text.$$
And i have argued that in the infinitesimal case $(x-a)^2$ is very small compared to $(x-a)$ thus i can write $f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)$ and this is linear as $f(a)$ and $f'(a)$ are constant.

My friend did this in following way.
He did $f'(x)-f'(a)=(x-a)f''(a)$ and taking the limit $x$ tending to $a$ on both sides, thus $f'(x)=f'(a)$. My problem with his method is when you are taking the limit of both sides as $x$ tends to $a$  both sides will vanish as $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)-f'(a)= \lim\limits_{x \to a} (x-a)f''(a)$. It implies that $f'(a)-f'(a)=0$ (taking the limiting values) and it means $0=0$.

Please clarify which one is correct.

Comment: Note that both methods use $ f ' ( a ) $, so you can't say that *any* function is linear in the infinitesimal limit, but only that *differentiable* functions are.

Comment: $f'(x)-f'(a)=(x-a)f'(a)$ seems to have a typo and presumably was intended to be $f(x)-f(a)= (x-a)f'(a)$ or $f'(x)-f'(a)=(x-a)f''(a)$.  Even with sufficient smoothness, neither need be exactly true when $x \not= a$ and, as you say, in the limit as $x \to a$ each would show $0=0$.

Comment: I'd say that your explanation is better, because the other one is either based on a wrong equation, or (making the correction that @Henry suggested) begs the question.  As for whether your explanation is *correct*, I don't think that you'll get a solid answer to this without a precise definition of how your infinitesimals work; these are difficult to treat rigorously.  But as a rough hand-waving idea, it's correct (as long as $ f ' ( a ) $ exists).

Comment: By the way, if you want to ask more questions here, it will be helpful if you [learn to write with MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  You can look at my edit to your question to get started seeing how it works.

Comment: Well this is wrong if $f(a)=f'(a)=0$ in which case the first significative term is $(x-a)^2f''(a)$ assuming $f''(a)\neq 0$. For instance take $f(x)=x^2\cos(x)$ in $a=0$.

Comment: At best, these arguments apply only to functions that equal their Taylor Series.  Thus the function not only has to be infinitely differentiable but it must be "smooth".  What would you do with a function like $F(x)=\exp\left(-1/x^2\right)$ for which all derivatives vanish at $0$, but which is not identically $0$ in any neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: @zwim please tell me how to show it correctly

Comment: Can someone give a proof of my above question .it will help me a better understanding of the procedure to solve the problem

Comment: @Hilbert There's no way anyone can help you with a proof since the statement is not only not precise but also false for arbitrary functions.